# billingClient!!.queryProductDetailsAsync does not return any products from Google play console

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing, google-play-billing

I am implementing a subscription with Google billing in my android application.
I have followed [Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) official documentation.
I have created subscriptions in Play Console and added relevant functionalities to my application.

The problem is, no subscriptions coming to the app from the Play console, always `billingClient!!.queryProductDetailsAsync` method returns an empty `productDetailsList`.

**Can anyone please help me to identify the problem here?**

here is my implementation,

In my app-level gradle file,

```
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.1.0"
```

In my subscription file

```
 private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //Setup billing
    billingSetup()
 }

 private fun billingSetup() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
        .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .build()

    //Connect to Google Play
    connectToGooglePlay()
}

private fun connectToGooglePlay() {
    billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Log.i("payment_flow", "OnBillingSetupFinish connected")
                queryProduct()
            } else {
                Log.i("payment_flow", "OnBillingSetupFinish failed")
            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.i("payment_flow", "OnBillingSetupFinish connection lost")

            //Re-connect to Google Play
            connectToGooglePlay()
        }
    })
}

private fun queryProduct() {
    val productList = ImmutableList.of(
        Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId("monthly_plan")
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build(),
        Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId("yearly_plan")
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build()
    )
    val queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList).build()

    billingClient!!.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { 
    billingResult: BillingResult, productDetailsList: List<ProductDetails> ->
    Log.d("payment_flow", "onProductDetailsResponse: 1: $billingResult")
        if (productDetailsList.isNotEmpty()) {
            tmpProductDetailsList.addAll(productDetailsList)
            Log.d("payment_flow", "onProductDetailsResponse: " + productDetailsList.size)
        } else {
            Log.i("payment_flow", "onProductDetailsResponse: No products")
        }
    }
}
```

Subscriptions on the Play Console
[image]

Logs when opening the subscriptions page in the app
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: No, still I couldn't find any solutions. I have reached the Google support team too, but they couldn't identify the issue.

Comment: Im here also facing the same problem. But out of 3 subscription products, I can only see 1 of them. I set them up yesterday so maybe it takes some time to propagate.

Comment: I just fixed my issue, all of my 3 products are showing. Unfortunetly I dont understand Kotlin, I use JAVA but what I can say is that my problem was how I was looping through the results of ProductDetails

Comment: @RobbyLebotha I have the java version of the code too. Can you see this drive file? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1khXF0DPW5J3NqXDyIemxHn9VdxMKxOPD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Waseem Have you uploaded your app to Google Play? I have uploaded my app to Google Play and published it (internal testing is enough). The product list now appears.

Comment: @DelphiQin Yes, published through internal track. But no use

Comment: @RobbyLebotha I have published the app to internal testing track then add the tester email address and "accept" the internal invitation. But still, the `ProductDetails` is returning empty. It's been several hours (~3 hrs at least). Do you recommend wait a few hours more?

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was i just created the subscription in google play console. there was 2 base plans, one weekly and one monthly. it was returning the weekly details not the montly. after so much searching in the code i thought maybe it takes time for newly created subscription, turns out google caches the products in your device. i selected the Google play app on my device and in the app info page i just selected the **"Clear data"** so all cached data was cleared and now it works just fine and returns all the products.

Comment: I was struggling with this for 1.5 hours, thank you

Comment: And yet the [documentation for this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryProductDetailsAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetailsResponseListener)) says "Performs a network query the details of products available for sale in your app.". Brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Clear Google Play App data and try again.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, but tried and it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Ok my issue was that my products were not showing up in my UI so I surrounded my looping and displaying of my products in a thread. Below is my code, hope it helps. Other than that, your code looks the same as mine. So key point, `runOnUiThread` . My products are loading perfectly now and can purchase.

```
billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
            params,
            (billingResult, productDetailsList) -> {
                // Process the result

                Log.d(TAG,"Got list queryProductDetailsAsync "+productDetailsList.size());

                for (ProductDetails productDetails : productDetailsList){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Got productDetails: "+productDetails.getName()+"\nDesc: "+productDetails.getDescription());

                    String productName = productDetails.getName();
                    String productPrice = productDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0)
                            .getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice();
                    String productID = productDetails.getProductId().toString();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (productDetails.getProductId().equals(Subscriptions.MONTHLY)) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"Got product Subscriptions.MONTHLY");
                                cvMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                tvTitleMonth.setText(productName+"\n"+productPrice);
                                tvDescMonth.setText(productDetails.getDescription());

                                btnBuyMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        launchPurchaseFlow(productDetails);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            if (productDetails.getProductId().equals(Subscriptions.BI_ANNUAL)) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"Got product Subscriptions.BI_ANNUAL");
                                cvSixMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                tvTitleSixMonth.setText(productName+"\n"+productPrice);
                                tvDescSixMonth.setText(productDetails.getDescription()
                                        +"\nYou save 40% compared to Monthly Subscription");
                                btnBuySixMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        launchPurchaseFlow(productDetails);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            if (productDetails.getProductId().equals(Subscriptions.ANNUAL)) {
                                Log.d(TAG,productName+"\n"+productPrice);
                                cvAnnual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                tvTitleAnnual.setText(productName+"\n"+productPrice);
                                tvDescAnnual.setText(productDetails.getDescription()
                                        +"\nYou save 40% compared to Monthly Subscription. Only " +
                                        "pay once a year.");
                                btnBuyAnnual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        launchPurchaseFlow(productDetails);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            if(loadingDialog != null){
                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: My problem is, "Got list queryProductDetailsAsync" is always return 0

Answer (score 0):

Re-check all configs for your subscriptions and confirm that all of theme opened for right regions.[image]